# How to remove ContextMenu highlight effect?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have the following context menu attached to a rectangle:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="criteria1" IsHitTestVisible="True">
 <Rectangle.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height=".5*"/>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Amplitude percentage"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" mah:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" mah:ControlsHelper.FocusBorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Width="70" >
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Criteria1AmplitudePercentage" TargetNullValue="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" />
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Bandwidth percentage}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" mah:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" mah:ControlsHelper.FocusBorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" Width="70" >
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="Criteria1BandwidthPercentage" TargetNullValue="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" />
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
            </Grid>
    </ContextMenu>
</Rectangle.ContextMenu>
```

On mouse hover I get this highlighting effect where the background turns dark grey:

[image]

**How can I remove this highlighting effect?**

**UPDATE**

The context menu appears only via right click. When setting `ContextMenu Background="Red"` and `Grid Background="Red"`, the menu looks like this:

[image]

When the mouse enters or is inside the menu or even if I click inside the text boxes, it looks like this:

[image]

**EDIT:** This is the default `ContextMenu` style:

```
        <Style x:Key="ContextMenuDefaultStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuPopupBackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MenuPopupBorderBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.DropShadowKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemFonts.MessageFontFamilyKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemFonts.MessageFontSizeKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemFonts.MessageFontWeightKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                    <Border Uid="Border_93">
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.DropShadowKey}}"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Effect">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" Opacity="0.8" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Uid="Border_50">
                            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}" Uid="ScrollViewer_9">
                                <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Uid="ItemsPresenter_5"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: You'll just need to go kill it in the style template of the control, which I wasn't able to find in their docs but if you extract and post it here I'm sure someone could quickly show you the pieces to ditch in it. Or just saw ContextMenu for PopUp

Comment: @ChrisW. Isn't this the template: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744758(v=vs.100).aspx ?

Comment: No, that is an example. I added the default `ContextMenu` style to your question. Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: @jstreet since he's using MahApps metro it comes with it's own ContextMenu control which I assume is causing the override behavior providing the MouseOver effect in question. That would be the style template needed in this instance. CristianM Please right-click yours, select Edit Template -> Edit a Copy, and provide that one.

Comment: @ChrisW: the only `ContextMenu` i see comes from the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace. Please point out where within `Mahapps` namespace is located its own `ContextMenu`.

Comment: @jstreet not the [control](http://mahapps.com/controls/context_menu.html) itself, just the style template is needed. I assumed he wanted to keep whatever other parts are unique to the MapApps style from it. Unless he wants to just override the whole thing with his own style in which case it becomes even easier.

Comment: @ChrisW.: the `Style` i posted is for a `Mahapps` app.

Comment: @jstreet Are you sure? `x:Key="ContextMenuDefaultStyle"` and the lack of any sign of a MouseOver trigger would lead me to think it's just the default style?

Comment: @ChrisW.: The `x:Key` can be whatever you want. Don't blame me for the lack of a `MouseOver` trigger.... That's exactly the problem.

Comment: @jstreet Relax amigo, I think you may be interpreting something wrong. I'm more than familiar with the workings, generally when xKey name that ends with DefaultStyle I assume it as a default style. I don't use mahapps because I generally make my own everything. It was just a question, nobody is blaming you for anything bud. :)

Comment: @ChrisW.: I was being facetious about the _don't blame me_...:O)

Comment: @jstreet Oh, you know what I just realized. We're looking in the wrong place anyway. It's a logical child of ContextMenu, aka, MenuItem. We're looking at the wrong piece. It would make sense for there to be a MouseOver decoration as MenuItem. If you want go ahead and plop that out here and grab some points then it's just biding time until Friday beer:thirty lol. :)

Comment: Although realistically, just ditching ContextMenu and swapping for PopUp and triggering IsOpen of it on MouseOver would have made more sense for this scenario imo.

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes, i thought the same thing and i did pulled the `MenuItem` style, but it is somewhat complex and I'm probably missing out some `xmlns` because it doesn't recognize `PopupAnimation` property.

Comment: @ChrisW. If I use `<Rectangle.Popup>`, it says "The attachable property 'Popup' was not found in type 'Rectangle'".

Comment: Sure, that would be expected. I think you may have confused `PopUp` with `Tooltip` where PopUp is a seperate control.

Comment: @ChrisW. But how can I use Popup, if this is not the correct syntax?

Comment: Context Menu actually uses PopUp Control with an embedded Menu. So really you would just be doing <PopUp><YOURSTUFF></PopUp> instead of <ContextMenu><YOURSTUFF></ContextMenu>

Comment: @ChrisW. If I set `<Rectangle.ContextMenu> <Popup>` it says "The following type was expected: 'ContextMenu'". If I write  `<Rectangle> <Popup>` it says "The type 'Rectangle' does not support direct content".

Answer (score 0):

```
<ContextMenu Background="Transparent">
```

Isn't that all you need?

Comment: Instead of Transparent, set it to say - Red. Does the whole ContextMenu become red?

Comment: @CristianM Wait, I just read your question again. What does "mouse hover" means? Doesn't context menu appear only via right-click? If the problem only really shows during "hover", then you should show us how it looks like before "hover", and also what exactly you are hovering over.